# Katalon - Basic auth GET api request getting 401 error

Tags: api, authorization, katalon-studio

I am trying to setup a simple GET request and dont think the basic authorization details are being passed properly. I have a test case that calls the test case object like so:

```
WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('API Requests/SimpleGet', [('SchematicID') : SchematicID, ('api_url') : GlobalVariable.api_url]))
```

In this web service request object I put in the authorization details -> Update to HTTP Header.

After executing the test case I get a 401 error.

My username has a '\' character in it, I'm wondering if that needs to be escaped somehow? I've already tried '\\' which works in a Katalon variable for logging in via web authentication forms.

Thanks